# Numerical Series nature

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need someone to approve if my way to prove that the following numerical series is divergent.

- Consider the Series $\sum_{n=1} \frac{1}{ln(n+n^2+n^3)}$. following the comparison test i found that the series diverge.
- My approach:

  **since**  $e^n +\frac{n^2}{2!} +\frac{5n^3}{3!} \ge n+n^2+n^3$ **then**    $ \ln(e^n +\frac{n^2}{2!} +\frac{5n^3}{3!}) \ge ln(n+n^2+n^3) $

  **i.e** $\frac{1}{ln(e^n +\frac{n^2}{2!} +\frac{5n^3}{3!})} \le \frac{1}{ln(n+n^2+n^3)}$ **but since** $e^n +\frac{n^2}{2!} +\frac{5n^3}{3!} \sim e^n$  as $n\rightarrow \infty$

  **hence**$\frac{1}{ln(e^n +\frac{n^2}{2!} +\frac{5n^3}{3!})} \sim \frac{1}{n}$ where $\sum\frac{1}{n}$ is **divergent** according to Reimann and so we get that the sum $\sum_{n=1} \frac{1}{ln(n+n^2+n^3)}$ is also **divergent**.

Am i right doing so ?

Answer (score 1):

$\log(n+n^2+n^3)\leq\log(n^3+n^3+n^3)=\log(3n^3)\leq\log(n^4)=4\log(n)\leq 4n$ if $n\geq 3$. Hence
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\log(n+n^2+n^3)}\geq\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}
$$
which is divergent.

Answer (score 0):

$$\log{(n+n^2+n^3)} = \log{n^3} + \log{\left (1+\frac1{n}+\frac1{n^2} \right )} = 3 \log{n}+O\left ( \frac1{n} \right )$$

Thus

$$\frac1{\log{(n+n^2+n^3)}} = \frac1{3 \log{n}} + O\left ( \frac1{n \log{n}} \right )$$

Thus the sum diverges by comparison with, e.g., then sum over $1/n$ which diverges.